# What test to use to compare values from same population at different time points?

Tags: panel-data, spearman-rho

**The study**
We have 1500-2000 patients who we are investigating. We are measuring a biomarker levels (continuous numeric variable) at different time points. What I want to know is:

**(1)** Does the rank of the patient remain relatively the same within the population. That is to say for example, Patient above median stays above median, patient below median stays below median at two different time points ?

For the purpose of the study, the absolute value of the biomarker is less important than the rank of the patient within the population.

**(2)** I realize with a very large patient population, even relatively small changes in rank could be significant. Is there a test that is more stringent?

**The big picture:**

Basically we are measuring three time points. Day 1, Day 40 and day 100. We want to show that if intra-individual change between the three time points remain stable across our population - then measuring at day 1 and day 40 will be sufficient - (important for cost efficiency in the clinical setting). How does one go about doing this?

So far I have been using Spearman's correlation. Perhaps theres a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, I'm no expert, this could be useless, but... I don't know what kind of model best suits your data, but let's say the response is linear, do a linear regression analysis, with time values being the continuous explanatory/predictor values, but only use values 0-40 days. From that data extrapolate what the outcome result would be at 100 days and compare it to an actual regression analysis where you use all your data not only the measurements take between 0-40 days...